# Azure Functions ( Http Triggered) started throwing TaskCancelled Exception randomly

Tags: c#, .net, azure-functions, azure-http-trigger

**How do I go about troubleshooting this?**

- I have a couple of Azure functions that use the following trigger
  signature [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post").
- The functions are running on a consumption plan.
- They get triggered 2-3 times a day.

The function intermittently fails to trigger with the following exception:

Diagnostic from Azure shows that the task was canceled before the worker process was called.
[image: Diagnostic]

```
public class AlpacaSample 
{
    private ILogger logger;

    public AlpacaSample(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        this.logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AlpacaSample>();
    }

    [Function("AlpacaSample")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
    {
        try
        {
            this.requestData = req;
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var message = $"Received a trigger {requestBody}";
            this.logger.LogInformation(message);

            // Business logic removed for brevity 


            return await this.CreateStringResponse(req, "All Good");
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string responseMessage =
                   $"Error occurrend while handling the message. Error: {ex.Message} \n {ex}";
            this.logger.LogError(responseMessage);
            return await this.CreateStringResponse(req, responseMessage);
        }


    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseData> CreateStringResponse(HttpRequestData req, string msg, HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        var res = HttpResponseData.CreateResponse(req);
        res.StatusCode = httpStatusCode;
        await res.WriteStringAsync(msg);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Full Call stack :

```
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:352)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:108)
Inner exception Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvocationCanceledException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker+<InvokeCore>d__9.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /_/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/Workers/WorkerFunctionInvoker.cs:106)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase+<Invoke>d__24.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /_/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionInvokerBase.cs:82)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionGenerator+<Coerce>d__3`1.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /_/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionGenerator.cs:225)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:52)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<InvokeWithTimeoutAsync>d__33.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:581)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__32.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:527)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:306)
Inner exception System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException handled at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker+<InvokeCore>d__9.MoveNext:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker+<InvokeCore>d__9.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /_/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/Workers/WorkerFunctionInvoker.cs:101)
```

Just My Code call stack

```
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:352)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:108)
Inner exception Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvocationCanceledException handled at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw:
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker+<InvokeCore>d__9.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /_/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/Workers/WorkerFunctionInvoker.cs:106)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase+<Invoke>d__24.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /_/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionInvokerBase.cs:82)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionGenerator+<Coerce>d__3`1.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /_/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/FunctionGenerator.cs:225)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2+<InvokeAsync>d__10.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.cs:52)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<InvokeWithTimeoutAsync>d__33.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:581)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithWatchersAsync>d__32.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:527)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<ExecuteWithLoggingAsync>d__26.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.37.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.cs:306)
Inner exception System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException handled at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker+<InvokeCore>d__9.MoveNext:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker+<InvokeCore>d__9.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=4.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: /_/src/WebJobs.Script/Description/Workers/WorkerFunctionInvoker.cs:101)
```

Trace

````
6/1/2023, 7:45:03 AM
-
REQUEST
URL: https://******.azurewebsites.net/api/******
Response code: 0
Response time: 3.1 s
6/1/2023, 7:45:03 AM
-
TRACE
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to dotnet-isolated. Skipping WorkerConfig for language: java
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:03 AM
-
TRACE
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to dotnet-isolated. Skipping WorkerConfig for language: node
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:03 AM
-
TRACE
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME set to dotnet-isolated. Skipping WorkerConfig for language: powershell
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:03 AM
-
TRACE
Initializing Warmup Extension.
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:03 AM
-
TRACE
Initializing Host. OperationId: 'fd2e77ef-c3b6-4a31-9d77-24c0de283e1f'.
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:03 AM
-
TRACE
Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=4, OperationId=fd2e77ef-c3b6-4a31-9d77-24c0de283e1f
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:03 AM
-
TRACE
Loading functions metadata
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:03 AM
-
TRACE
Reading functions metadata
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
2 functions found
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
1 functions loaded
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
ApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions { "SamplingSettings": { "EvaluationInterval": "00:00:15", "InitialSamplingPercentage": 100.0, "MaxSamplingPercentage": 100.0, "MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond": 20.0, "MinSamplingPercentage": 0.1, "MovingAverageRatio": 0.25, "SamplingPercentageDecreaseTimeout": "00:02:00", "SamplingPercentageIncreaseTimeout": "00:15:00" }, "SamplingExcludedTypes": "Request", "SamplingIncludedTypes": null, "SnapshotConfiguration": null, "EnablePerformanceCountersCollection": true, "HttpAutoCollectionOptions": { "EnableHttpTriggerExtendedInfoCollection": true, "EnableW3CDistributedTracing": true, "EnableResponseHeaderInjection": true }, "LiveMetricsInitializationDelay": "00:00:15", "EnableLiveMetrics": true, "EnableDependencyTracking": true, "DependencyTrackingOptions": null }
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
LoggerFilterOptions { "MinLevel": "None", "Rules": [ { "ProviderName": null, "CategoryName": null, "LogLevel": null, "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0" }, { "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider", "CategoryName": null, "LogLevel": "None", "Filter": null }, { "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider", "CategoryName": null, "LogLevel": null, "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0" }, { "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider", "CategoryName": null, "LogLevel": "Trace", "Filter": null } ] }
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
LoggerFilterOptions { "MinLevel": "None", "Rules": [ { "ProviderName": null, "CategoryName": null, "LogLevel": null, "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0" }, { "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider", "CategoryName": null, "LogLevel": "None", "Filter": null }, { "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider", "CategoryName": null, "LogLevel": null, "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0" }, { "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider", "CategoryName": null, "LogLevel": "Trace", "Filter": null } ] }
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
ConcurrencyOptions { "DynamicConcurrencyEnabled": false, "MaximumFunctionConcurrency": 500, "CPUThreshold": 0.8, "SnapshotPersistenceEnabled": true }
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
FunctionResultAggregatorOptions { "BatchSize": 1000, "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30", "IsEnabled": true }
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
SingletonOptions { "LockPeriod": "00:00:15", "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:01:00", "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807", "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05", "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00" }
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
ScaleOptions { "ScaleMetricsMaxAge": "00:02:00", "ScaleMetricsSampleInterval": "00:00:10", "MetricsPurgeEnabled": true, "IsTargetScalingEnabled": true, "IsRuntimeScalingEnabled": false }
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
Starting JobHost
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
Starting Host (HostId=******, InstanceId=8f937b40-6d44-4919-******-ec66a372643a, Version=4.21.2.20699, ProcessId=5844, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=False, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=~4)
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
Generating 1 job function(s)
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
Found the following functions: Host.Functions.******
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
Initializing function HTTP routes Mapped function route 'api/******' [get,post] to '******'
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
Host initialized (12ms)
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
Host started (12ms)
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
Job host started
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
HttpOptions { "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": true, "EnableChunkedRequestBinding": false, "MaxConcurrentRequests": 100, "MaxOutstandingRequests": 200, "RoutePrefix": "api" }
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:04 AM
-
TRACE
Executing 'Functions.******' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=1fd81ebd-e455-4a79-a9e8-5a02972a124d)
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:06 AM
-
TRACE
Worker process started and initialized.
Severity level: Information
6/1/2023, 7:45:06 AM
-
EXCEPTION
Exception while executing function: Functions.******
Problem Id: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
6/1/2023, 7:45:06 AM
-
TRACE
Executed 'Functions.******' (Failed, Id=1fd81ebd-e455-4a79-a9e8-5a02972a124d, Duration=2825ms)
Severity level: Error
6/1/2023, 7:45:06 AM
-
EXCEPTION
Exception while executing function: Functions.******
Problem Id: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
6/1/2023, 7:45:09 AM
-
TRACE
Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '3caa8b34bd20508b527345686484c415'.
Severity level: Information```
````

Comment: Please show relevant code

Comment: Please let me know what code are you looking for. The execution did not even reach inside my code. I added some more snapshots from the Azure diagnostic in the original question.

Comment: Can you at least let me know what details are needed for the people voting to close this question? The exception happens before the Azure Function is invoked, and I am asking for pointers on how to debug this further.

Comment: Are you sure? Maybe there is some kind of `Task` related deadlock going on. Or how about show us what your trigger code is, and the entrypoint function for the trigger call.

Comment: I have added a sample code. I expect the first log message to be printed if we make it into the Run function if the exception is thrown from my code.

Comment: Hmm I don't know, it almost looks like some of Azure's internal trigger code is going into an infinite loop. Maybe raise it with support. Side note `string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();` you need to dispose the reader like thise `using var sr = new StreamReader(req.Body); string requestBody = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();`

Comment: Yeah, I have not been able to find a proper forum to get this resolved. I do have a using wrapper around that reads operation. I just removed the extra coverings for this post.

Comment: Might be a dead-end but have you tried publishing this as a WebJob (under an App Services application)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs due to an update to the underlying Azure runtime release at the end of May. The temporary workaround is to pin the Azure runtime to 4.17.3. This information was provided by Azure technical support.

Comment: Version 4.17.3 seems to be gone now, https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues

We are using 4.22.0.20804 and also experiencing this issues.

Comment: Yup, the issue came back for me too.

Comment: Have the same issue, but only in my local environment.

Comment: @AGCodes have you found the fix for this ?